# How to retrigger ng-if / ng-show animation when using $http cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angular-http, angular-ng-if

Within a factory service, I have to use

> $http.get(url, { cache: true })

In my view, i am using *ng-if* or *ng-show* to trigger a CSS transition.

**The problem :**

It is working great for the first request, but obviously for the next request of the same service function, the animation is not re-triggered.

**Is there a way to reset / retrigger the ng-if / ng-show animation ?**

(The cache is needed so i can avoid waiting time, but i still need to have opacity animation triggered between different states).

Thank you !

```
app.factory('progService', function ($http) {
    var progService= {};
    progService.getProgram = function() {
        return $http.get(appInfo.api_url + 'pages/5', { cache: true});
    };
    return progService;
});
```

```
app.controller('programController', function($scope, progService) {
    progService.getProgram().then(function(res){
        $scope.program = res.data;
    });
});
```

```
<div ng-if="program.aJsonKey"></div>
```

Comment: it's a bit confusing here, if you want to cache the request result, why do you want to trigger the ng-if animation? can you describe what does this animation do?

Comment: and also what is `program.acf.exerpt`？

Comment: @ZhiliangTakutoXing  Question updated.  It would be nice if you could upvote the question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably need to set up your own flag in this case. for example:

```
app.controller('programController', function($scope, progService) {

    $scope.programDisplay = false;

    progService.getProgram().then(function(res){
        $scope.program = res.data;
        angular.element(document).ready(function () { 
            $scope.programDisplay = true;
        });
    });
});
```

then

```
<div ng-if="program.acf.exerpt && programDisplay"></div>
```

Comment: Well finally it does work, but **only if** i put a setTimeout around `$scope.programDisplay = true;`, even at 1 millisec.  !!  Thank you !

Comment: how does it look like when it's not working if you dont use setTimeout? can you describe it?

Comment: If i don't use setTimeout, it seems the flag is always true (from 2nd request), never false, so the animation is not re-triggered. Putting a millisec gap makes the difference... The same trick is needed with the other answer from Yavor Ivanov

Comment: my guess will be, the $scope.programDisplay got resolved before the bowser actually process the whole html document. so how about try `angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        $scope.programDisplay = true;
    });`

Comment: This is the best answer.  Thank you.  I'll edit your answer.  Once approved i will set it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your view is not updated because you're passing the same, cached object.
In order to execute the $watcher of ngIf, you should provide a "fresh"/new object. You would also need probably to change the state, because ngIf would expect true or false.
So in your case should be something like this:

```
app.controller('programController', function($scope, progService) {
    $scope.program = null;
    progService.getProgram().then(function(res){
        $scope.program = angular.copy(res.data); // Returns a copy of the object. Always a new object!
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanx Yavor.  But the animation only retriggers if i put a short *setTimout* around `$scope.program = angular.copy(res.data);` **or** `angular.element(document).ready(function () { ` + `});` around it.  **But then** for both tricks the first request seems way longer.

Comment: You should avoid using setTimeout in Angular. There's abstraction over it and is called $timeout service, you should use it instead of pure setTimeout: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

And, yes, if your service is mocked/ does not make an AJAX call probably you won't get an animation, because you have a sync code.
Using timeout to show animation should be fine to trigger the animation

Comment: Also from your writing I see that it's DOM might not be ready yet. So workarounds are to use .ready() or $timeout/setTimeout.

Comment: Indeed...  i had other problems because of using additional sliders on the page.  So neither .ready() or setTimeout would work well (sometimes waiting for the other slider to achieve slide transition)...  Right now I am using $timeout which is way better, but not perfect (sometimes it still happen too early).  But i don't know much about $timeout, i guess i'll take better use of it in the future.